# Access denied: Permission bigquery.tables.getData denied on table while checking preview of table

Tags: google-bigquery, roles, user-permissions, access-denied, google-iam

Getting the error of Access denied: "Permission bigquery.tables.getData denied on table", while checking the preview of table.

I have created Custom role and assigned permissions to respected google user account.

1. bigquery.jobs.create
2. bigquery.jobs.get
3. bigquery.rowAccessPolicies.create
4. bigquery.rowAccessPolicies.getFilteredData
5. bigquery.rowAccessPolicies.getIamPolicy
6. bigquery.rowAccessPolicies.list
7. bigquery.rowAccessPolicies.setIamPolicy
8. bigquery.tables.create
9. bigquery.tables.get
10. bigquery.tables.getData
11. bigquery.tables.getIamPolicy

Predefined roles are assigned as-

1. BigQuery Admin
2. BigQuery Data Owner
3. BigQuery Data Viewer
4. BigQuery User
5. Owner
6. Custom Role
7. Fine-Grained Reader
8. Policy Tag Admin

Please check what is hampering me in checking the PREVIEW of table. Attaching the screenshot for the same.
[image]

Please help me in removing the error.